# how to change permissions for current view overriding the DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES in django rest-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, token, access-token

how to change permissions for current view overriding the `DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES` in `django rest-framework`

Here  is how i set my defaultpermissions in my `settings.py` :

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',  # <-- And here
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ]
}
```

and i need to use `AllowAny` on the `signUp` method :

```py
@permission_classes([AllowAny,])
@api_view(["POST", ])
def add_new_user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        lang = request.data["lang"]
..........
.........
.......
```

Still, it returns `Authentication credentials were not provided.` .. I mainly need to have permissions with a token with every request but not the register and login request. how to do it ??

Comment: based on drf docs default permission must be overridden when use the decorator..
check your code with doc example 
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/

Comment: `Note: when you set new permission classes via the class attribute or decorators you're telling the view to ignore the default list set in the settings.py file.` that is what they say and that is how it should work but it not .

Comment: I guess the order of decorators is important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved this :

in my `settings.py` i added both permissions classes

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',  # <-- And here
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',  #both are mentioned 
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ]
}
```

and in my `view`, I had to move the permission dictator to be the last thing before the view itself.

```py
@api_view(["POST", ])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def login_user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        lang = request.data["lang"]
...
```

Answer (score 1):

A Way to do that is using Object Level Permissions in Django.
You just setup as normally in settings.py and add manually a permission into every class view.
For me is the best way to do it. Normally will be Views witch is are Admin only, Authenticated or just Open.

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication', 
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoObjectPermissions',#Object Level Permission
        
    ]
}
```

After set this line into your settings.py just follow adding a permission_classes into view. Like:

```py
class LoginUser(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny, ]
    ...
```

**References**

[DjangoObjectPermissions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#djangoobjectpermissions)

[Django Class Based Views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/)